# TextWriterTraceListener trace file too large

Tags: c#, .net, logging, trace, rollingfileappender

I am using C# `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener` to print trace. But the trace file becomes too large (hundreds of MBs). 
I want to change the behavior of `TextWriterTraceListener`, that if the trace file becomes large, it writes output to another file. 
For example, the original trace file is 'output1.txt', if it becomes larger than 100MB, then TextWriterTraceListener should write to 'output2.txt'.

Have you encountereds similar problems? Are there any elegant solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Two options I can think of:

1. Write your own `TextWriter` implementation that does this, and set the `TextWriterTraceListener.Writer` property to an instance of it. Here's a [sample](http://weblogs.asp.net/DaveBost/archive/2004/04/30/124224.aspx) implementation that does this, although it rolls over on a time (daily) basis rather than on a file-size basis.
2. Switch to [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) and use a `RollingFileAppender`.

Comment: +1 - log4net will solve this problem and has other features to offer like conditional logging

Comment: Sample page linked to in answer no longer exists, archived link is https://web.archive.org/web/20040628122447/http://weblogs.asp.net/DaveBost/archive/2004/04/30/124224.aspx